# Scrape with Beautiful-Soup from site that uses AJAX using Python

Tags: python

i want to scrape the product name,price and image source from the page but only limited result will display here is website which i want to scrape https://www.walmart.com/browse/cell-phones/unlocked-phones/1105910_1073085 
and i also want to scrape the check box of fillers but don't know about how to scrape all result but only 10 result display what should i do to scrape complete result .If i remove headers than display complete result of names and prices but  image sources are not scrape {

```
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0",
           "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
           "Referer": "http://thewebsite.com",
           "Connection": "keep-alive"}



    scrap = requests.get('https://www.walmart.com/browse/cell-phones/unlocked-phones/1105910_1073085',headers=headers)


    # Grab title-artist classes and store in recordList
    content = BeautifulSoup(scrap.text, "html.parser")



    if content.findAll("div", {"class": "search-result-gridview-item-wrapper"}) != None:
        products = content.findAll("div", {"class": "search-result-gridview-item-wrapper"})

        for product in products:
            name = product.find("div", {"class": "search-result-product-title gridview"})
            title = name.find('a').text

            price = product.find("div", {"class": "search-result-productprice gridview enable-2price-2"})
            p = price.text

            image=product.find("div",{"class":"display-inline-block pull-left prod-ProductCard--Image"})
            img = image.find("img", {"class": "Tile-img"})['src']

            hreff = product.find("div", {"class": "display-inline-block pull-left prod-ProductCard--Image"})
            href=hreff.find('a')['href']


    if content.findAll("div", {"class": "search-result-listview-item clearfix"}) != None:
        products = content.findAll("div", {"class": "search-result-listview-item clearfix"})

        for product in products:

            if product.find("span",{"class":"Price-group"}) !=None:
                name = product.find("a", {"class": "product-title-link"}).text
                price = product.find("span", {"class": "Price-group"}).text

                image = product.find("div", {"class": "display-inline-block pull-left prod-ProductCard--Image"})
                img = image.find("img", {"class": "Tile-img"})['src']

                hreff = product.find("div", {"class": "display-inline-block pull-left prod-ProductCard--Image"})
                href = hreff.find('a')['href']
```

}

Comment: Use selenium webdriver for this

Comment: sir how can i use don't know any thing about it @Aritesh

Comment: The issue with BeautifulSoup is that it simply takes the content of current page, and doesn't interact with the page. Your requirement is to interact with the page, for that you will need a webdriver

Comment: sir how can i use the web driver

Comment: @Aritesh sir please tell me how can i use the selenium webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Please see below the sample code to scrape data from this website. I have just added on interaction, but this should give you general idea - (You need to use inspect element functionality of your browser to find xpaths)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver") #download chromebrowser
browser.get("https://www.walmart.com/browse/cell-phones/unlocked-phones/1105910_1073085") #open page in browser
outDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['prodname', 'imageurl', 'minprice', 'maxprice', 'actualprice']) #template of data
prices = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'price-main-block')]") #finding prices
product = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'product-title-link')]") #product name
images = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@class, 'Tile-img')]") #images

#getting actual prices/ranges
for i in range(len(product)):
    prodname = product[i].get_attribute("aria-label")
    imageurl = images[i].get_attribute("src")
    pricerange = prices[i].find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'Price-group')]")
    if len(pricerange)>1:
        minprice = pricerange[0].get_attribute("title")
        maxprice = pricerange[1].get_attribute("title")
        actualprice = None
    else:
        minprice = None
        maxprice = None
        actualprice = pricerange[0].get_attribute("title")
    thisline = [prodname, imageurl, minprice, maxprice, actualprice]
    outDF.loc[outDF.shape[0]] =  thisline

#Reading next pages    
next = True
while next:
    try:
        #clicking next button
        browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'paginator-btn paginator-btn-next')]").click()
        #repeating process
        prices = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'price-main-block')]")
        product = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'product-title-link')]")
        images = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@class, 'Tile-img')]")
        for i in range(len(product)):
            prodname = product[i].get_attribute("aria-label")
            imageurl = images[i].get_attribute("src")
            pricerange = prices[i].find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'Price-group')]")
            if len(pricerange)>1:
                minprice = pricerange[0].get_attribute("title")
                maxprice = pricerange[1].get_attribute("title")
                actualprice = None
            else:
                minprice = None
                maxprice = None
                actualprice = pricerange[0].get_attribute("title")
                thisline = [prodname, imageurl, minprice, maxprice, actualprice]
                outDF.loc[outDF.shape[0]] =  thisline
    except:
        print("Something went wrong")
        next = False

browser.quit()
```